# ExtJS 4 - grid column tpl implementation

Tags: templates, extjs, grid

I'm trying to add the string "item " into every row under an "Item No." column in a standard ExtJS 4 grid.

I've attempted

```
confirmationGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'confirmationGrid',
    width: 1100,
    renderTo: Ext.get('sencha_confirmation'),
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Item No', width: 80, dataIndex: 'ItemNo', tpl: 'item {ItemNo}' }
        // additional columns removed for brevity
    ]
});
```

and all the references (store, model) to the item number are `ItemNo` (as above).  The column is ignoring the tpl stipulation and is simply displaying the item number without any additional text.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `renderer` to get the desired result in the column:

```
       {
            text: 'Item No',
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'ItemNo',
            renderer: function(value) {
                return 'Item: ' + value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `xtype: templatecolumn` that indicates that you're using a template. Also, you didn't show your data, so perhaps also:

1. Your model is missing that field
2. The server didn't return data for that field